# Qt Installer Framework environment variable

Tags: qt-installer

How to add an Environment variable ( a directory C:/test1/bin)  in System variable path( not in User variable ) using Qt Installer framework?
I have tried like this,

*component.addOperation ("EnvironmentVariable", "PATH","C:/testl/bin", true)  ;*

But this adds in User variable Path, Please help me to modify this so that the value will get added in System variable path.

Answer (score 0):

I use the reg to solve：

```
if(installer.isInstaller())
{
    var pathText = "D:\\test"
    var reg = installer.environmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\System32\\reg.exe";
    var RegV="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\SessionManager\\Environment"
    component.addOperation("Execute", reg, "ADD", RegV , "/v", "pathText", "/t", "REG_SZ", "/d", pathText,"/f");
}
```

You can use the "REG ADD /?" in powershell to find the help.

Please note that this installer need call gainAdminRights():

```
function Component()
{
    component.loaded.connect(this, this.installerLoaded);
    installer.installationStarted.connect(this,Component.prototype.onInstallationStarted);
}
Component.prototype.onInstallationStarted = function()
{
    installer.gainAdminRights();
    installer.execute("cmd.exe", ["/c", "timeout " + "5"]); 
}
```